# paypal payment getway to accept the credit card or using paypal account

Tags: php, paypal

I need to setup paypal payment get-way on website.

customer can pay using credit card or using there paypal credential on my website.

not to redirect to paypal .

I have already setup website payments pro for credit card.

I don't know how to enable to also accept the paypal account credential for payment .

how can setup using sandbox.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

To use PayPal along side direct credit card use ExpressCheckout to give the Checkout with PayPal option, https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec

Using this you create a token to redirect users to PayPal, they log in and continue back to your site, PayPal provides you with the information from the users account (name,address,etc.)

You can use this information to process the payment as well as fill out any fields you need your users to fill out before checking out.